# Can't fork on github

Tags: github

I'm trying to fork a random repo on github but it doesn't work. All that happens is that I arrive at a page where I'm asked "Where should we fork this repository?" and a symbol of my avatar. I can hover the avatar and it becomes highlighted but when I click it, nothing happens. I'm using Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I don't have private browsing turned on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like it should be [sent to GitHub's support team](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: I actually found that it works using Firefox. So maybe a Safari issue.

Comment: Firefox doesn't work but Chromium works, on my computer. :(